# query pertaining to scribe (for twitter auth) and twitter api v1.1

Tags: twitter-oauth, scribe

Twitter API v1.0 is being retired today (unless I am completely mistaken - which is quite possible).  I am wondering what changes need to happen in scribe (besides changing the auth url) - has anyone else encountered the same issue and how have they gone about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply changing the URL from 1 to 1.1 worked so far for me.  Any other suggestions/info/caveats would me quite welcome.

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json");
```

Comment: it appears I need to use the token to fetch the image as well - something I did not implement previously.